# How do I populate a list field variable in Ansible (jinja2, yaml) without inserting the unicode 'u' prefix?

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, jinja2

For my python application, I am trying to create and populate a list field in a config file created and deployed by Ansible.  Right now it just has one list element (phone_number_), in the future it could have more, hence being a list.

In my jinja2 yaml template I have:

```
FIELD_NAMES: {{field_names}}
```

And in my variable var yaml file I have:

```
field_names: ['phone_number_']
```

The resulting config file deployed to be server has this line produced:

```
FIELD_NAMES: [u'phone_number_']
```

I don't want that unicode "u" in there.  How can I get rid of it?

Comment: try: `FIELD_NAMES: {{str(field_names)}}` or switch to python 3

Comment: "*the resulting config file*" - resulting from what? Where is the code? And what is "*jinja2 yaml template*" supposed to mean?

Comment: @techraf This is jinja2.  http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/

Comment: I did not ask "what is Jinja2", I asked what does "*jinja2 yaml template*" mean? It's still visible in the comment above. Do you mind answering the question?

Comment: Roles in Ansible can be made up of sub-directories: handlers, tasks, templates, vars, etc.  The templates sub-directory can contain jinja2 files.  For example, a template directory could contain a file called config.yaml.j2.  In that file, variables are declared, like in my case, FIELD_NAMES: {{field_names}}.  Here's an example of a templates directory used in a role: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/tree/master/tomcat-standalone/roles/tomcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `to_json` and `to_yaml` [filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data), that may be helpful.

```
FIELD_NAMES: {{ field_names | to_json }}
```

Will give you clean JSON list without unicode markers:

```
FIELD_NAMES: ["phone_number_"]
```

Comment: FIELD_NAMES: {{ field_names | to_json }} solved my issue.  The config file being deployed by ansible now has FIELD_NAMES: ["phone_number_"].  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a list with one element:

```
field_names: ['phone_number_']
```

I see two options:

1) Reference the variable in your jinja2 template as:

```
FIELD_NAMES: {{field_names[0]}}
```

2) Define the variable as a string:

```
field_names: 'phone_number_'
```

Comment: Those would both work, but as soon as a the list array became longer than one element, I think we would run into trouble.

Comment: What is the problem if the array become longer? It can be iterated with a loop, or just reference the element you need.

Comment: In this case, the elements and position of the elements in the list array is unpredictable.  But iteration may work... How would you iterate a multi-element array list with a loop?